# Where do I add my Route 53 subdomain's NS records?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a domain registered with namecheap and its DNS records are managed by AWS Route 53. Currently the domain points to a regular EC2 instance. I'd like to get a subdomain set up pointing to a separate EC2 instance (specifically, an Elastic Beanstalk instance). I've got the Beanstalk instance set up (so if I visit the elastic IP for that instance, everything works fine).

THe problem is, all the docs I've seen on adding a subdomain to Route 53 imply that the parent domain's DNS records are still managed by the registrar. I'm unclear as to where I need to add the new NS records for the subdomain in order to have it point to the right thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an example of a domain hosted at namecheap.com, DNS handled by route 53, website hosted on aws ec2 instance and the email server is hosted at Rackspace email.

Your situation is pretty close to this, so you should be able to follow this example and change to your specifics:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, all I had to do was add a new A record with the name of my subdomain and value of the elastic IP of the new ec2 instance

Comment: This answers a lot of questions.