# Having trouble setting up subdomain hosted on AWS, through NameCheap

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2.4, namecheap

I bought a cheap domain on Namecheap.  It is hosted on an AWS EC2 Linux Ubuntu instance.  I set it up through Route 53.  The root domain works correctly.

What I'm trying to do is get a subdomain working, such as apex.rootdomain.com, and I am having much more trouble than I thought.  I figured it would be much easier than setting up the root domain (which was actually pretty simple due to a great article I found).

Here is my apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /html/root>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /html/apex>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is my config file in etc/apache2/sites-available/MyConfig.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /html/root
        ServerName www.root.com
        ServerAlias root.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName apex.root.com
        DocumentRoot "/html/apex"
</VirtualHost>
```

I believe that My apache2.conf and MyConfig.conf are both correct , because they work for my main domain.

Here is how I set up the subdomain on Route 53:

1. I created a hosted zone for my subdomain.

   - This resulted in NS and SOA records sets.
2. I then went to the hosted zone for my main domain name.
3. I created a new NS record for apex.root.com in the hosted zone of root.com
4. I copied and pasted the 4 addresses from step (1) into the record set in step (3)
5. I copied and pasted the addresses from (4) into the 'Name Servers' in my Namecheap dashboard.  I now have a total of 8 Name Server addresses in Namecheap (4 for root domain, 4 for subdomain)

### Edit

Just to add, I waited about 2 or 3 days just to see if the issue would resolve itself, but it has not.  Namecheap said that it takes less than 48 hour for changes to take effect.

EDIT: ZONE FILE

Hosted zone for root.com

```
NAME                               TYPE    VALUE
root.com.                            A      Elastic-IP


root.com.                            NS   Domain-Name-A.
                                          Domain-Name-B. 
                                          Domain-Name-C. 
                                          Domain-Name-D.

root.com.                           SOA   some values that I don't think matter

www.root.com.                         A   Elastic-IP
apex.root.com                         A   Elastic-IP
```

Name Servers: Domain-Name-A, Domain-Name-B, Domain-Name-C, Domain-Name-D, Domain-Name-E, Domain-Name-F, Domain-Name-G, Domain-Name-H are listed as 'Name Servers' on Namecheap.

Here is what my Namecheap setup looks like:

```
NameServers

Customs DNS
- Domain-Name-A
- Domain-Name-B     
- Domain-Name-C
- Domain-Name-D
```

Comment: subdomains get weird, in the DNS... did you try just apex instead of apex.root.com?  It could be registering as "apex.root.com.root.com"

Comment: Yeah I did.  But its definitely registered as apex.root.com because I tested the record set in Route 53 and it came back good.  I think something is messed up in Namecheap.  But the only configuration needed in Namecheap is to copy the server names from the NS record sets, so I'm not sure how I could have messed that up.

Comment: did you try to ping the domain names to see what IP address comes back? sure fire way to see what's pointed where.  `ping apex.root.com`

Comment: So when I do that, I get 'ping: cannot resolve apex.root.com: Unknown host'.  So I guess this means that its definitely something with Namecheap config?

Comment: May need to post your zone file to see what's going on, obv replacing IP address and domain names accordingly.

Comment: I added the zone info as an edit.  I think thats what you are looking for

Comment: subdomains can be on the same zone file as the primary domain.  treat www like a subdomain because that's all it really is. do the same for apex as you do for www... assuming that www.root.com works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming root.com and www.root.com work in your current config, it would be as follows:

```
root.com.                            A      Elastic-IP
www.root.com.                        A      Elastic-IP
apex.root.com.                       A      Elastic-IP
```

keeping in mind that on GoDaddy for your DNS it would be as follows:

```
@                                    A      Elastic-IP
www                                  A      Elastic-IP
apex                                 A      Elastic-IP
```

Comment: Okay, I tried this.  I edited my post again to show my current config.  It might take a while to see if the changes worked.

Comment: Are these edits on NameCheap or Route 53? If it's on NameCheap fine, lets isolate the problem to see if this works. If these edits are on Route 53 then we need to also make sure NameCheap is forwarding properly to Route 53.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH.  You don't understand how much trouble this has been causing me.  Thank you for taking so much of time to help me!

Comment: If it's working, and those edits are on NameCheap, then we're bypassing Route53.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383785/where-do-i-add-my-route-53-subdomains-ns-records) for suggestions on how to forward to Route 53.

Comment: Those edits I was making were being done on Route 53.  Look at my most recent edit to see what my Namecheap looks like

Comment: As long as NameCheap isn't touching that Elastic-IP address then it's configured properly. It needs to hand-over all instruction to Route 53. Sounds like you got it :)

Comment: Anytime, best of luck with your new project